# JasperReports Error evaluating expression for source text

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When I tested the report on JasperSoft Studio it's working fine.

[image: error]

but when I exported report and test it on my main project I get this error:

> Error evaluating expression for source text:
>   IF($F{jdpmarc}.equals(""),new java.math.BigDecimal(0),$F{jdpprit})

I have tried these things:

Changing this expression because it's a BigDecimal operation

```
IF($F{jdpmarc}.equals(""), 0,$F{jdpprit})
```

for this

```
IF($F{jdpmarc}.equals(""),new java.math.BigDecimal(0),$F{jdpprit})
```

this is my code:

```
Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","user", "password");

    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("Proforma", 67929);

    String reportPath = "ReporteIva.jasper";

    JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, data, conn);

    JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(report);
    viewer.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Use ternary operator instead

Comment: @DavidSantos You should post small and full jrxml and full stacktrace

Comment: Make sure you have a jasperreports-functions jar on your application's classpath.  If you do have the jar, post the full exception stacktrace (including Caused by.. lines).

Comment: Error given is because I'm using expressions

Answer (score 0):

try with ternary operator,

```
$F{jdpmarc}.equals("") ? new java.math.BigDecimal(0) : $F{jdpprit}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dada67, for me it was enough to add jasperreports-functions-xxx.jar (in my case, I'm using version 6.6.0)